# Header PHP redirect sloop

Tags: php, redirect, http-redirect

After reinstalling my VPS server, i get the following code when refreshing my page:

> "This webpage has a redirect sloop"

this happens when my php script are trying to use this line:

```
header( 'Location: http://lucianomafia.net/innbrudd' ) ;
```

It was working before my VPN reinstall, but not now.

any idea why?

code:

```
@session_start();
$RequestSignature = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].print_r($_POST, true));


if ($_SESSION['LastRequest'] == $RequestSignature)
{
  header( 'Location: http://lucianomafia.net/innbrudd' ) ;

}
else
{
  $_SESSION['LastRequest'] = $RequestSignature;
}
```

If a user do a refresh, it will send the post requests aswell :( . To prevent this it will load the site from its start.

Comment: Where does `http://lucianomafia.net/innbrudd` redirect to?

Comment: wrong .htacces / rewrite rules

Comment: BENM: The link you are providing me is the same page. If a user do a refresh, it will do all the POST`s aswell. and to prevent this it will load the site from its start. Im now providing more code in my post.